# Code: 0, SQL State: 42601 ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER"

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am getting an error when trying to create the below function using DbVisualizer / redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION business_days_between(start_date DATE, end_date DATE) RETURNS INTEGER
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
DECLARE
total_days INTEGER := DATEDIFF(day, start_date, end_date);
weekdays INTEGER := total_days - (DATEDIFF(week, start_date, end_date) * 2);
holidays INTEGER := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp.holidays WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date);
BEGIN  RETURN weekdays - holidays;
END;$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

[Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER"

I was expecting to create a function similar to one I have done in SQL, thought it was might be my version of DBvis so upgraded to the latest version. also google lots of suggestions but nothing as helped so far.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot declare variables in [user-defined SQL functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html) in Redshift.

You would need to rewrite the function. It must only contain a `SELECT` clause without any `FROM`, making UDFs very restricted.